# Uploading image as blob in Mysql | Flutter

Tags: php, android, mysql, flutter, blob

I am currently creating a program with the flutter framework, and I need to upload images to a hosted database in a blob datatype. Is it possible to do through flutter framework where image taken from camera can be uploaded as blob?. If yes can you show me how to do it.

PS: I am using PHP for accessing my database from the webhost.

I've been searching through the web, and only I can find is through directory, or maybe I did really not done enough searching

Answer (score 0):

If you are store blob format on mysql then Try logngText attribute

[more detail](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings)

you can change default column format

```sql
ALTER TABLE `tableName` MODIFY `columnname` LONGTEXT
```